# How do I reinstall/enable snapper?

Tags: opensuse, btrfs

I had errors in my root filesystem (btrfs) so I recreated it from a backup but now, `snapper` doesn't work anymore:

```
# /usr/bin/snapper -v -v -v -v create --description test
IO Error.
# snapper -v  delete-config 
Deleting config failed (deleting snapshot failed).
# snapper create-config /
Creating config failed (subvolume already covered).
# snapper -c root create-config /
Creating config failed (subvolume already covered).
# snapper list
Type   | # | Pre # | Date | User | Cleanup | Description | Userdata
-------+---+-------+------+------+---------+-------------+---------
single | 0 |       |      | root |         | current     |
```

I also tries to reinstall/remove and install the package `snapper` but without any luck.

Any ideas how I can make `snapper` work again?

openSUSE 12.3 with kernel `3.7.10-1.1-desktop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to delete/rename the file `/etc/snapper/configs/root`
2. Edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/snapper` and remove `root` from the variable `SNAPPER_CONFIGS`

Now snapper should work again:

```
> snapper create-config /
> snapper list
Type   | # | Pre # | Date                     | User | Cleanup | Description | Userdata
-------+---+-------+--------------------------+------+---------+-------------+---------
single | 0 |       |                          | root |         | current     |         
single | 1 |       | Wed Apr 17 22:40:01 2013 | root |         | test        |
```

If it still doesn't work, then maybe you need to delete defective snapshots. Use `btrfs subvolume delete /.snapshots/...` for this (kudos go to [JonathanS](https://superuser.com/users/423328/jonathans)).